# Finding matching value in sheet 2 and copy adjacent cells value in sheet 1

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have searched through many similar topics but could find nothing that will do what I need.

I am trying to create a worksheet that will track scores for a darts game.

On **Sheet 1** I have two columns that simply tracks each players throws from 501 down to 0

**Row 25** is the amount remaining for each player.

In **Sheet 2** I have 2 columns. The **Column A** contains scores that you can check out on, and **Column B** contains the checkout *e.g. (T20, T20, D18)*. So if the value in **row 25 of Sheet 1** matches any of the values in **Column A of sheet 2**, the I want to display the Value of **Column B** *in the matching row on **Sheet 2*** Underneath the remaining score on **Sheet 1**.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you mean exactly, but this formula in row 26 should do the trick:

```
=index('Sheet 2'!$B:$B;match(A25;'Sheet 2'!$A:$A;0))
```

- if your list separator is comma `,`, use that instead of semicolon `;`
- you might want to use `1` as the third argument of match function, if you want to display the checkout according to the nearest match that is bigger than the number in row 25 and the column A in Sheet 2 is sorted in ascending order (1-9)
- or `-1` if you want the nearest match that is smaller and column A is sorted in descending order (9-1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4, Sheet2!$C$2:$E$65535, 3, FALSE),0)
```